# React pass state to nested components not working

Tags: reactjs, state

I am not using redux because its too hard to understand for me :(

So i tried pass the state to nested components but no luck.

Code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwx43y2843

I would like to made the component `Nested`  work same as component `Two`, Input onChange and change the text in realtime.

I think the problem maybe at this line.

```
<Nested state={this.props.state} />
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `props` inside your Nested component:

```
class Nested extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Nested</h2>
        <div>FirstName: {this.props.state.firstName}</div>
        <div>lastName: {this.props.state.lastName}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pay attention to the **.props** that comes after **this**!

Comment: fastest ctrl+c ctrl+v in the west

Comment: Thanks so much, BIG thanks, just one more thing wanna to ask, can i pass the handleChange to nested? like this <Nested state={this.props.state} handleChange={this.props.handleChange} />? i tried but no luck, i have a updated example https://codesandbox.io/s/jnzl88mmk9

Comment: you forgot to pass it in the Two. `<Two state={this.state} handleChange={this.handleChange} />`

Answer (score 1):

You pass it like `<Nested state={this.props.state} />` but to get the state you need to get from `props`

```
class Nested extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Nested</h2>
        <div>FirstName: {this.props.state.firstName}</div> // added .props
        <div>lastName: {this.props.state.lastName}</div> // added .props
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j0oo3jvv9)

Comment: `<Nested>` doesn't have any state

Comment: sorry, just edit it, it was a typo

Comment: I also added an example

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `props` from the `Nested` component. You have `this.state.firstName`, it needs to be `this.props.state.firstName`.

Also, you don't need to worry about Redux while just learning React or smaller applications - but as soon as you start doing a lot of handing of state to props, it comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't call a prop state

So what is the state you would like to pass? because you seem to passing props called state, this is very confusing in react.

### Some examples to explain the concept

You can see here passing variables, these become the props in the child component

#### Parent component render method

```
render() {
  const car = {id: '123'};
  return <CarDisplay car={car} />
}
```

#### Child component render method

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props) // this will have car inside
  return <div>{this.props.car.id}</div>
}
```

If you have state in a parent component it still becomes props when it's rendered by the `CarDisplay` (Child component) component.

#### Parent component with state

```
class car extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {car: {id: '123'}}
  }
  render() {
    const { car } = this.state;
    return <CarDisplay car={car} />
  }
}
```

Don't use state unless you want to change it with the `setState` react method. Props are read only so use them do display data etc.

Comment: This info help me alot, because i have so many state need to pass, but i tried use this method, it seem have some issue with my dynamic setstate function (handleChange), here is the updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/lp835yro7q , is that my function problem or i pass the wrong state to components? console no error show, thanks